# jQuery.localScroll not working only in Windows Chrome (OSX Chrome and all other Windows browsers work fine)

Tags: jquery-plugins, scrollto

Just discovered this anomaly where the plugin seems to be totally unresponsive on Windows Chrome 33. I've read through the other closed issues and some similar Stack Overflow questions but to little avail. I'd be interested to know if anyone else has had this problem and what their solution was. You can see the website in question here: http://wvandaal.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this ended up being pretty specific to my own setup: I've been working with the web-components spec and had a bunch of experimental features enabled in `chrome://flags`. The solution was to disable `Experimental Web Platform features` and restart my browser.